# What is the correct position for sich?

Tags: word-order

I found this sentence in a text I am studying:

> Und immer wenn sich die Geschichte
>   änderte, sich also das Leben der Menschen merklich veränderte, änderte sich
>   natürlich auch die Sprache.

There are 3 instances of "sich". Each is placed in a different position in the clause without apparent reason. Would the following rearrangement be equally correct?

> Und immer wenn die Geschichte sich
>   änderte, also das Leben der Menschen merklich sich veränderte, änderte sich
>   natürlich auch die Sprache.

Answer (score 1):

In such sentences, there is indeed more than one position to where the *sich* can go. Your guess for the first one is correct, in the second one you are by one word off, though. It would have to be:

> Und immer wenn die Geschichte sich änderte, also das Leben der Menschen **sich** merklich veränderte, änderte sich natürlich auch die Sprache.

Comment: Can you give me an explanation why the second one could not be placed where I placed it? Is it because it must come before any adverbs?

Comment: @anonymous: An easy, but non-formal reason: *sich* relates to *_Leben_ der Menschen*, *merklich* belongs to *veränderte*. It is so unusual, to permute the words destroying those connections, that a native speaker would not use your order, especially when speaking (as opposed to writing).

Comment: From an English native speaker's point of view, sich is a very mysterious word. It's clear that it can alter the meaning of the associated verb. But your comment that it "relates to" the subject rather than the verb in the case of das Leben, ich verstehe nur Bahnhof. Any clues as to how to understand this?

Comment: Wenn er das Wort in einem Text fand, den er studierte, dann geht es aber doch wohl in erster Linie um geschriebene Sprache, nicht gesprochene. Adorno schrieb viele solche Sätze: "Die Ursache war nur der letzte philosophische Begriff, an dem wissenschaftliche Kritik sich maß, gleichsam weil er allein von den alten Ideen ihr noch sich stellte, die späteste Säkularisierung des schaffenden Prinzips." (TWA, Dialektik d. Aufklärung)